# How to feed multiple prompts to OpenAI-DotNet/API sequentially?

Tags: .net, openai-api

I'm using OpenAI-DotNet to integrate OpenAI API in my c# app and following the REAME.md on this gitHub repo - https://github.com/RageAgainstThePixel/OpenAI-DotNet#chat-completions

I'm trying to give the AI model a few step-by-step prompts including:

1. Prompt1:*"Please read the following paragraph:"*
2. Prompt2:*"the space is intended for ....."* (the actual paragraph)
3. Prompt3:*"Please tell me if this paragraph mentioned a person named xxx"*

This is fairly easy to do using ChatGPT interface - I just input the 3 prompts sequentially and it responds well. However, using OpenAI-DotNet wrapper, it doesn't seem to take multiple prompts and "think" about them wholistically. The README.md has the following sample code for Chat Completions -

```
var api = new OpenAIClient();
var chatPrompts = new List<ChatPrompt>
{
    new ChatPrompt("system", "You are a helpful assistant."),
    new ChatPrompt("user", "Who won the world series in 2020?"),
    new ChatPrompt("assistant", "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."),
    new ChatPrompt("user", "Where was it played?"),
};
var chatRequest = new ChatRequest(chatPrompts);
var result = await api.ChatEndpoint.GetCompletionAsync(chatRequest);
Console.WriteLine(result.FirstChoice);
```

However, when I try mimic that with my own prompts:

```
var api = new OpenAIClient();
var chatPrompts = new List<ChatPrompt>
{
    new ChatPrompt("user", Prompt1),
    new ChatPrompt("user", Prompt2),
    new ChatPrompt("user", Prompt3),
};
var chatRequest = new ChatRequest(chatPrompts);
var result = await api.ChatEndpoint.GetCompletionAsync(chatRequest);
Console.WriteLine(result.FirstChoice);
```

It sometimes return "I'm sorry but there's no paragraph provided for me to review,..." which sounds like it didn't actually get Prompt2, or didn't notice it's provided.

What is a good way to provide "step-by-step" instructions when using the API?

Thanks!